# Updating a dynamic dropdown list in excel upon change in cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to create a form which hopefully updates the list of values for a particular dropdown list automatically (without VBA codes) upon user's input immediately.

Here is the form that the user will see:

[image]

Currently, both Columns F and H is based on a data-validation formula:

```
INDIRECT("VList!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($B11,VList!$1:$1,0),1),"1","")&"2:"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($B11,VList!$1:$1,0),1),"1","")&COUNTA(INDIRECT("VList!"&ADDRESS(1,MATCH($B11,VList!$1:$1,0),4)&":"&ADDRESS(100,MATCH($B11,VList!$1:$1),4))))
```

... where `VList` refers to the sheet as shown below:

[image]

So my question here is, based on the Project Name in Column B, is there a way to update the list in sheet VList with the value `"Cost Per Unit" [Cell E11]`, so that the dropdown list in `F12` and `H12` get automatically updated with the value `"Cost Per Unit"`?

Been researching a long time for this with no avail, so I'm hoping to seek some experts here to see if such a scenario is even possible without VBA. Thanks!

**Edit:** So I've been told that VBA codes can be triggered automatically upon changes in the cell value, so I am open to any solutions/help with VBA as well. Will be researching on that direction in the meantime!

**Edit2:** Added a simple illustration below that hopefully better depicts what I'm trying to achieve on excel:
[image]

***Edit3:** I'm starting to explore the Worksheet_SelectionChange method, and this is what I've come out so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim projectName As String
    Dim VariableList As Worksheet
    Dim Form As Worksheet

    Dim thisRow As Integer
    Dim correctColumn As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Set VariableList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VList")
    Set Form = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")

    On Error GoTo EndingSub

    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        thisRow = Target.Row
        projectName = Form.Cells(thisRow, 2)

        correctColumn = Application.Match(projectName, VariableList.Range("1:1"), 0)

        lastRow = VariableList.Columns(correctColumn).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        VariableList.Cells(lastRow + 1, correctColumn).value = Form.Cells(5, thisRow).value

    End If

EndingSub:

End Sub
```

Somehow the value of `Form.Cells(5, thisRow).Value` is always empty.

If I change it to `Target.Value` it still takes the previous value that was being input (e.g. I first put "ABC" as New Variable, it doesn't get updated. I changed New Variable to "DEF", it updates the list with "ABC" instead of "DEF"). It also takes ALL the values that are under Column E somehow.

Also, pressing Enter after I placed one input in E11 also causes both values of E11 and E12 to be updated when only E12 has been changed. However if I click away after E11 is being input, then only E11's value gets updated.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You cannot update another cell's value with a formula, only the cell that the formula is contained in. Is there a reason you don't want to use VBA?

Comment: @SOofWXLS, can't use VBA because the requirement for now is to update the list immediately once cell E11 gets an input value. I don't suppose there is any way of triggering a VBA code from such an action? Thus seeking opinions here if it's even possible

Comment: Actually, that's exactly the kind of thing to use VBA for.... it's called a change event and is a very common use for VBA

Comment: @SOofWXLS oh, so VBA allows for automaticatic code runs upon events (such as a change in cell value)? Okay thanks for the tip, I'll try to research towards that direction now in the meantime!

Comment: This might get you started: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

Comment: @lyk can you add an image of the expected behaviour you are looking for? an extended example will do. thanks

Comment: @AHC, hi, what I'm trying to achieve is basically is that once the user types in "Cost Per Unit" in the form under NewVariable (Column E), this get automatically updated in the VList Sheet, under the Column A which has the "Project1" header. "Cost Per Unit" will be updated in the list in cell A6. Do you still require an image for this?

Comment: @AHC added an image, hopefully it is slightly clearer?

Comment: It's much clearer. Hopefully you'll get flooded with answers, especially if you change/add the tag for Excel VBA.

Comment: @user3819867 oh yea, thanks for that! have added in, as I previously didn't think it was possible with vba =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was almost having fun with this one, if anyone can refine the screwed-up parts feel free to amend.
I furthermore recommend using tables. I do realise you can write lengthy formulae to refer to ranges but giving a name to your table gives an expanding list with a simple reference.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim NewVar As Range
On Error GoTo Err
Set NewVar = Range("C:C") 'data entered here, could be a referstorange kind of named range reference
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Intersect(Target, NewVar)) <> 0 Then Call ertdfgcvb(Target, NewVar) 'only run if there's an intersect, f*ed up but works anyway
Err:
End Sub

Sub ertdfgcvb(Target As Range, NewVar As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet, Valid As Long, project As String, ListElmnt As String, Unlisted As Boolean, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set ws = Sheets("VList") 'the data that you refresh
Valid = 2 'projects in column B
HeaderRow = 1 'headers in Vlist are in row #1
uRow = Cells.Rows.Count 'f* yeah, compatibility considerations

For Each Cell In Intersect(Target, NewVar) 'will evaluate for each cell individually, in case you were to insert columns
    ListElmnt = Cell.Value2            'stores the prospective list element
    r = Cell.Row                       'stores the list element's row to...
    project = Cells(r, Valid).Value2   'identify the related project

    HeaderRowRef = HeaderRow & ":" & HeaderRow
    ColumnNum = ws.Range(HeaderRowRef).Find(What:=project, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column   'finds the project in VList
    'MsgBox ws.Name
    Set rng1 = ws.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, ColumnNum)
    Set rng2 = ws.Cells(uRow, ColumnNum)
    LastRow = ws.Range(ws.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, ColumnNum), ws.Cells(uRow, ColumnNum)).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'finds the last row for the project in VList 'f*ed up but works
    Unlisted = True                                                                  'assumes it's unlisted
        For x = HeaderRow + 1 To LastRow
            If ListElmnt = CStr(ws.Cells(x, ColumnNum).Value2) Then Unlisted = False 'unless proven otherwise
        Next
    If Unlisted Then ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, ColumnNum) = ListElmnt                    'if it's unlisted it gets appended to the end of the list
Next
End Sub
```

EDIT:
How to purge the table, example:

```
Sub ert()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("Táblázat1")         'obviously the table name
Do While x < rng.Rows.Count          'for each row
    If rng(x, 1).Value2 = "" Then    'if it's empty
        rng(x, 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp 'then delete but retaining the table format
    Else
        x = x + 1                    'else go to the next line (note: with deletion comes a shift up!)
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: See uploaded [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-773Ttgo1z6anVJXzJNekllS0U/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Now that I think about it, you could simply accept other variables (not in list) and then run the same sub. In this case your current column would become obsolete thus input would be more convenient.

Comment: omg this solution is brilliant, thank you so much! I just need to edit a little more to replace the wrong values (e.g. user typed "Testing" but found out is a typo, should be "Testing1", and thus "Testing1" should replace "Testing".

Comment: and anyway, I can't really use tables because VList is also produced from VBA codes and will be cleared and refreshed with new data periodically... hard to explain but yea..

Comment: is there a way to .Find using the previous cell value under NewVariable and replace it with the correct one?

Comment: Been trying Target.Value under the selectionChange method but still not working so far

Comment: Target may or may not be a single cell, I wouldn't recommend using `Target.Value`. The previous VList position can be stored in a global variable  replacing `HeaderRow + 1` or calculated again from the description given by you. The global variable is not recommended as you'll need to apply an exception rule for the first time it is used (after opening the workbook). The second option doesn't give you any advantage, takes more computing.

Comment: Deletion from a table can be done through `Ctrl -` or using simple methods such as the one described in my edit.

Comment: ahhh i see... sadly I can't really used the Table method as I can't set the data in VList into a table format due to reasons stated earlier.. but I'll try to find alternatives in the meantime, thanks!